# Why is output shown only alternately?

Tags: java, java-7

```
public class Two {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(obj.nextInt() > 5)
    {

        System.out.println(obj.nextInt());
    }
}
}
```

If i input the number ( > 5) for first time there is no output on the console but if i input a number on second try there is output on the console.
So I get an output alternatively.
Can anyone explain why is it so?

Comment: When you call `nextInt()` the second time you will try to read another  `int` from the console.

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: You are printing every alternative input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting output every other input is because you're prompting the `Scanner` object to gather input twice within your loop system. Every time you call a `next...` method on your `Scanner` you are prompting the user.

So in your condition for the `while` loop you are asking the user to input a value integer value which is then compared against `5`. THEN, in your print statement you call the `nextInt()` method again, which will then prompt the user again for another value integer input.

So given a series of 6 integer inputs for your current loop, `6 2 10 4`, you loop will only print `2` and `4`.

Instead, you should prompt and store once outside of your loop, then test with the condition and reprompt after the print within the loop like so...

```
int input = obj.nextInt();
while (input > 5){
    System.out.println(input);
    input = obj.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! actually i was trying to print without storing it .

Answer (score 3):

The *java.util.Scanner.nextInt()* method Scans the next token of the input as an `int` and returns it. After the token is read another `nextInt()`-Call will read (as the name says) the *next* Integer.

I think you were expecting something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int read;

    while((read = scanner.nextInt()) > 5)
    {
        System.out.println(read);
    }
}
```

Now the read Integer is stored in the variable `read` and is printed, if it was greater than five.